# Login request is still going through even though validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm fairly new to using ASP, as most of my web development experience comes from outdated methodology.

Anyway, I am using FluentValidation to validate form entries.

> **LoginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

> **LoginValidator.cs**

```
public class LoginValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Username).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Username cannot be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password cannot be empty.");
    }
}
```

And I'm running this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
//Validators
services.AddSingleton<IValidator<LoginViewModel>, LoginValidator>();
//FluentValidation
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
{
     fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
});
```

And this is how I'm handling the login request in my `UserController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
    var user = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == login.Username && x.Password == login.Password);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Invalid username/password combination.");
        return View();
    }
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username));
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

However, when submitting a blank login form, I end up with this:

[image]

If the validation fails, why is the login request still being submitted?

Do I have to also validate within the UserController, or is there something I'm not quite doing right?

Comment: what are you getting in `var user = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == login.Username && x.Password == login.Password);` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I would expect it not to get to that point if the validation fails.

Comment: I could manually validate it in the controller, but then what's the point in adding to services etc?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind. I figured out that using `ModelState.IsValid` works, which saves me having to manually validate the model again before submitting the login request.